# npm script runs default script even if parameter is different

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-scripts

In my package.json I heve these scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "do-build": "ENV=DEV node ./src/setEnvironment.js",
    "do-build:prod": "ENV=PROD node ./src/setEnvironment.js",
    "do-build:dev": "ENV=DEV node ./src/setEnvironment.js"
  }
```

So, I assume that when I run `npm run do-build` it will run `"do-build": "ENV=DEV node ./src/setEnvironment.js"`, and when doing `npm run do-build --prod` it would execute `"do-build:prod": "ENV=PROD node ./src/setEnvironment.js"`, but it always executes the default do-build script(`"do-build": "ENV=DEV node ./src/setEnvironment.js"`). I am not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

npm does not support CLI arguments that influence which script should be executed. Therefore `npm run do-build:prod` will execute the production build task.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how npm scripts work. If you want to run do-build:prod you would have to do it like so: `npm run do-build:prod`

Your npm scripts can accept parameters if you like, eg if you had this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "echo $1"
  }
```

You could run it like so: `npm run foo bar` and your script would receive bar as the 1st command line parameter.

To have richer support for command line options, I'd suggest you look into richer task runners such as gulp or grunt instead of using npm scripts.

Comment: If I use this npm run do-build prod I get prod in process.argv values array, but only after my node bin directory path and .js file path that I am pointing to. Maybe you can help me to understand why it is so and how prevent these paths from getting into this array?

Comment: You can't prevent those paths from appearing in argv, that's just how node works by design https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv